# Splitting a text document and matching only the first string

Tags: c#, regex

I am parsing a web page to get some data.

A part of that code is like this

```
<div class="persona_name persona_level">Level 
    <div class="friendPlayerLevel lvl_20">
        <span class="friendPlayerLevelNum">25</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="friendPlayerLevel lvl_400 lvl_plus_10">
    <span class="friendPlayerLevelNum">417</span>
</div>
<div class="friendPlayerLevel lvl_200 lvl_plus_10">
    <span class="friendPlayerLevelNum">217</span>
</div>
```

I am not really familiar with RegEx and was thinking of using string.split.

Anyway, I just want it to return the first value. See where it says "25" in the first line. I want that number, not the other two.

P.S. - They will always be in this order. The number I want will always be the first in the document..

How can I achieve this?

Comment: are you grabbing the source of the web page and trying to do this or are you crawling it and tech like jQuery might be available?

Comment: im grabbing the source code.

Comment: Use [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) to parse html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the first span in the file that contains just a number, assuming your html is a string variable called "html", you could use something like the regex-based approach below:

```
int number;
var rx = new Regex("<span class=\"friendPlayerLevelNum\">([0-9]+)</span>");
var match = rx.Match(html);

if(match.Success && Int32.TryParse(match.Groups[1].Value, out number))
    Console.WriteLine("Got the number: {0}", number);
else
    Console.WriteLine("not found")
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Should not this be a comment?

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a regex for this you can try this:
`(>\d+<)` This grabs the first group of the following : >25<, >0<, >2500000< You will have to strip off the ">" and "<" but this will work assuming it is the first group and always has at least one number.

**EDIT**

Here is a more precise regex and you wont have to strip off any tag charsacters

```
friendPlayerLevelNum">(\d+)
```

Comment: there might be numbers present before that. the link i am parsing is the following http://steamcommunity.com/id/xxbone

Comment: I took the page source and ran that and it worked I can get you something more specific.

Comment: yes but its not necessary it will always be 25. on other profiles, that number might be different

Comment: that will match any digit 0- your hearts content